# Missing Passwords Login keyring after fresh Ubuntu desktop 18.04 LTS installation

Tags: 18.04, login, password

Noticed that password use of keyring had problems. Mysql Workbench complained at everything having to do with keyring. Started seahorse to check. Turned out that the Passwords:Login category that usually is the first listed in left column is missing. The obvious action is to create it as many help articles suggests.
Problem is that the create operation get greyed out hangs forever after i entered 'Login' and pressed OK.

Since this was a plain clean install i would have expected 1) Passwords:Login keyring to be present. 2) a lot of question on this topic if it is missing after clean install. Not so.

Relevant files present:

$ ls -a .local/share/keyrings

.  ..  login.keyring user.keystore

Is there a command line alternative to bypass seahorse and get the Passwords:Login keyring operational? Other work arounds i havent thought of or not been able find?